# Keep absolute element (dropdown-menu) in viewport or window width

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drop-down-menu

```
<li class="dropdown">
                  <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">DROPDOWN <span class="caret"></span></a>
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu menu-multicolumn">
                        <li class="menu-column">
                            <ul>
                                <li class="menu-column-title">Multi Page</li>
                                <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Something here</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>

                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li class="menu-column">
                            <ul>
                                <li class="menu-column-title"></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Something here</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>

                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li class="menu-column">
                            <ul>
                                <li class="menu-column-title">One Page</li>
                                <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Something here</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li class="menu-column">
                            <ul>
                                <li class="menu-column-title"></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Something here</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                  </ul>
                </li><!-- End of dropdown -->
```

Css

```
 .dropdown-menu {
background-clip: padding-box;
background-color: #fff;
border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
border-radius: 4px;
box-shadow: 0 6px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.176);
display: none;
float: left;
font-size: 14px;
list-style: outside none none;
margin: 2px 0 0;
min-width: 160px;
padding: 5px 0;
position: absolute;
text-align: left;
top: 100%;
z-index: 1000;}

.menu-multicolumn {
white-space: nowrap;
width: auto !important;}

.menu-column {
display: inline-block;
float: none;
overflow: hidden;
vertical-align: top;
white-space: normal;
min-width: 190px;}
```

Ok so now i was thinking with javascript to determine how much .dropdown-menu element is out of window width and then to set that same width as left: -(that width);, so .dropdown-menu element will have flexible left position and will always be inside window width.

Basically i need to determine how much element is out of window width and then set that same amount as minus left absolute position of that same element.

Comment: If you need a detailed question add some css to your post! Do your submenus display as boxes side by side or from top to bottom etc.

Comment: Its bootstrap dropdown code with my small modification and dropdown works great. And i can set class .dropdown-menu-right and it will start with right: 0; position but that is not what i want. I know how to calculate element width and window width but how can i see how much of that element width is out of window width, and if i can determine this i can easily set that amount as minus left position on div. I am noob with javascript and i am not sure if this is even posible but it would be cool if it is. Thanks for help

Answer (score 2):

Maybe its thought too simple, but if I get you the right way, and you always want the right side to stay inside your viewport, you could simply do this:

```
.dropdown-menu {
   position: absolute;
   right: 0px;
   left: auto;
}
```

Instead of calculating how much you should push the left side in a negative margin you can simply set the space to your right side to zero!